# Solved MSI - GE62 2QC freeze during LoL - Kernel Error 37

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, freeze

My computer is a fairly new (MSI - GE62 2QC) and I have not been having problems with it until lately.

It has an i7 5700 HQ, Geforce GTX 960M, and 8GB RAM

The problem is that for the past week, right after I installed CS:GO (probably unrelated), every time I start a League of Legends game the PC freezes completely. After restarting the laptop by removing the power I can play the rest of the game without it freezing again. I also played Rocket League and Dark Souls 3 (heavy game) without any problems or freezes.

**What I have tried**

- Clean installing the GPU drivers (373.06) using DDU in safe mode (just installer, without using GeForce Experience)
  Updating
- BIOS to the latest version using the link from MSI website (version E16J2IMS.119) and installed them using a USB and going into BIOS mode.
- I have set LoL to run specifically on the GPU and not global settings.
- I have tried running League of Legends as administrator.

Looking at the event viewer I find that at the time of the freeze 8 yellow warnings are generated:

> Event 37: "The speed of processor X (1-8) in group 0 is being limited by system firmware".

I am out of ideas so I am asking for help.

Comment: How hot does the laptop get before it crashes? (Reason for asking: `the speed of the processor...` sounds like thermal throttling.)

Comment: it feels quite hot actually; but still even if i just start my pc and run LoL it will still crush ( not enough time for pc to get hot ... at least thats what i think)

Comment: The whole PC/laptop does not need to get hot. Just one part getting to hot is enough. E.g. if the i7-5700 gets to hot it will assert the PROCHOT line and stop processing. That might look like a freeze.

To check if it is this or an other problem run something like coretemp of GPU-Z and keep them on a different screen than the game you are playeing (assuming you game full screen, else just put the windows next to eachother). And for completeness test with a few other programs like prime95 or CPU-Z, or a graphics benchmark (for both heat generation from CPU and GPU).

Comment: Running RealTemp while playing rocket league got me these MAX temps which look high : 77°C - 82°C - 83°C - 79°C. So probably you are correct, thanks for the help! May i ask how i proceed from here? Do i contact my supplier or can i solve this alone ? Thanks again!

Comment: make that 89 - 90 -91-90 celcius

Comment: Max temp before auto shutoff for this CPU is 105C. (See http://ark.intel.com/products/87716/Intel-Core-i7-5700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_50-GHz?q=I7%205700%20HQ). But yes, that is high. Are the air vents clean? No dust in the heat sink? Etc?

Comment: Yes the laptop is fairly new so pretty sure that the fans are clean. I still think it is related to something Geforce drivers and LoL/CS:GO because they the only two games that crush. But thanks for your help ! Wish me luck :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is here after all ... : http://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support-en/bARQFu3O-windows-10-anniversary-update-causing-fps-issues-and-crashes

A windows update change caused it.